# SQL Server query for calculating sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL query for calculating sum without success.

Let's say that we have:

- table `A` with columns `id` and `type`
- table `B` with columns `id`, `a_id` (relation to table `A`) and `amount`

I succeed to calculate number of records by `type` like in the following example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    type,
    COUNT(A.id) OVER (PARTITION BY type) AS numOfRecords
FROM A;
```

How to calculate sum of amounts also per `type` (to sum up all amounts from table `B` for all distinct types in `A`)?

Comment: If you want to sum something, what's wrong with [`SUM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? Why are you using `DISTINCT` and `OVER` when clearly what you really want is a `GROUP BY` clause?

Answer (score 4):

Your query would normally be written as:

```
select type, count(*) as num_records
from A
group by type;
```

Then, you can incorporate `b` as:

```
select a.type, count(*) as num_records, sum(b.amount)
from A left join
     (select a_id, sum(amount) as amount
      from b
      group by a_id
     ) b
     on b.a_id = a.id
group by a.type;
```

You can also `join` and `aggregate` without a subquery, but this will throw off the count.  To fix that, you can use `count(distinct)`:

```
select a.type, count(distinct a.id) as num_records, sum(b.amount)
from A left join
     from b
     on b.a_id = a.id
group by a.type;
```